# How to create a widget that adjusts itself according to some image size?

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm very new to Flutter, and I came with a background knowledge of Swift, Kotlin, and React Native. I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1) and so far the result is good till the end. It shows a tiled list of popular movie poster images. This is the code that primarily render (build) the individual tile.

```
Widget buildList(AsyncSnapshot<ItemModel> snapshot) => GridView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.results.length,
  gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    ResultsListBean result = snapshot.data.results[index];
    return Image.network('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${result.posterPath}', fit: BoxFit.cover);
  }
);
```

Now I want to add the title of the movie below the image, *while keeping the size of the tile grid*. I modified the code like this:

```
Widget buildList(AsyncSnapshot<ItemModel> snapshot) => GridView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.results.length,
  gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    ResultsListBean result = snapshot.data.results[index];
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.network('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${result.posterPath}', fit: BoxFit.cover),
          Text(result.title)
        ]
      )
    );
  }
);
```

with the assumption that because the grid tile height is fixed, the text will push the image upward, thereby shrink its weight, as I do not set the image width and height explicitly. But this resulted in a warning on each individual tile "Bottom overflowed by 106 pixels".

How should I fix this? I have the feeling that the solution to this is fairly simple, but I didn't find anything about that so far when reading tutorial on api.flutter.dev. I'm thinking about this from react native flexbox perspective, and trying to apply the similar knowledge to the flutter widget.

EDIT: I have trying to used the Expanded widget on Image, but the result is the the Image widget is trying to shrink until it can contains the whole image in proportional, without clipping, which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still interested, here is the answer.

1. Use the `ImagePixels` widget from the https://pub.dev/packages/image_pixels package to read the original image size.
2. Calculate the position and place your title according to the height/width of the image, using for example using a `Stack`/`Positioned`, or a [AlignPositioned](https://pub.dev/packages/align_positioned).

```dart
ImagePixels(
    imageProvider: image,
    builder: (context, img) =>
       Stack(
          children: Positioned( ...
                        // Calculate position using img.width and img.height...
                    ),
              );
```

*Note: I am the author of the packages I linked above.*

Comment: @martijn-pieters This answer is actually tailored to the question. The question is similar but it's not identical to others, and the answer is also similar but not identical.

Comment: Amazing. I can't try it right now because I'm working on ReactNative project at the moment. But there will be time where I will work on Flutter again, so I will keep note for this answer. I don't know that there's such plugin that can give me actual width and height of the image. Thanks!